# CRecordset Addnew get Autonumber

Tags: sql-server, mfc, ms-access-2013, recordset

I am working on an old MFC app which uses CRecordset to work with Databases (SQL/Access/Oracle).

There is a table which has an AutoNumber as the PK column.
When the app does an AddNew() on that table, I want to get the Autonumber assigned to the new row. This number is then used to insert rows in other tables.

To achieve this, right now we are doing an AddNew and the querying the table again, sorting rows descending order and using the top row to get the last number just inserted.

This is fine for a single user, but runs into issues with MultipleUsers and concurrency.

I want to know how should this be handled.

Comment: Doesn't [CRecordset::Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2d9aefb.aspx) populate the primary key field?

Comment: No, if I addNew and Update, it takes me to the first record on the table (not the one which I added)